# How to save R base graphics as an object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, save, circlize

I have a chord diagram built using the circlize package.  Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to save this as an object.  I would like to have the plot be an object (especially a ggplot obkect) so that I can modify some of the surrounding text and export it to xlsx. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: [`?recordPlot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/recordplot.html) or [`?ggplot2::ggsave`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html).

Comment: Those links talk about saving to objects, but it sounds like you want a lot more than just saving it. Perhaps `svg("file.svg"); ggplot2(...); dev.off();` and then edit the SVG file elsewhere.

Comment: I do want to save it as an object, but currently I only have a base R plot built using the circlize package.  Saving the plot with the traditional '<-' produces an object that lists the original data

Comment: `plot(1); y <- recordPlot(); y;` does not list the original data, did you try it? If you then close the plot (`dev.off()`) and then `y` (or `print(y)`), the same plot reappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options from various packages:

ggplotify:

```
g <- as.grob(~plot(runif(10)))
grid.draw(g)
```

cowplot:

```
plot(runif(10))
p1_recorded <- recordPlot()
ggdraw(p1_recorded)
```